Angular 18: How to redirect on result of resolve
In Angular 18, I am trying to resolve a value before navigation, but redirect to another page based on that value.
Please don't link to a page titled "Redirecting Guards and Resolvers in Angular v18" by Davide Passafaro. It doesn't answer my question.
Here is the scenario:

A path parameter is passed in the URL named key.
I am using that key to obtain a value (that describes a piece of artwork) from the backend referenced by that key.
If a valid value is returned I want that value bound to the component.
If I receive a null value instead, I want to redirect to another page that displays a 404 - not found message.

Here is what I have so far:
const routes: Route = [
   path: ":key",
   component: ArtComponent,
   resolve: {
      art: () => inject(ArtService).get(key)      // This automatically binds to a corresponding @Input() property on the component
   },
   canActivate: [
      () => {
         const router = inject(Router);
         *** somehow redirect to 404 page if art is null ***
         return true;
      }
   ]
];

I'm obviously missing something. The alternative is to perform a redirect within the ngOnInit() function on the ArtComponent, but that sounds icky.

The guard runs first then the resolver.
So we fetch the data in the guard by returning the observable and use map to access the data inside and determine to redirect or not.
      canActivate: [
        (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
          console.log('guard');
          const router = inject(Router);
          const artService = inject(ArtService);
          return artService.get(route.params['id']).pipe(
            map((data: any) => {
              route.data = { ...route.data, temporaryData: data };
              if (!data) {
                return router.createUrlTree(['/']);
              }
              return true;
            })
          );
        },

We also need to share this data to the resolver, here we add a property temporaryData which contains the data from the API, which we then access in the resolve to return for the @Input binding.
      resolve: {
        art: (
          route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
          state: RouterStateSnapshot
        ) => {
          console.log('resolve');
          const temporaryData = route.data?.['temporaryData'];
          // delete route.data?.['temporaryData'];
          return temporaryData;
        },
      },

Full Code:
import { Component, Injectable, inject, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  provideRouter,
  RouterModule,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router,
  withComponentInputBinding,
} from '@angular/router';
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ArtService {
  get(key: any): Observable<Object | null> {
    return key === '1' ? of({ data: 1 }) : of(null);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    child: {{art | json}}
  `,
})
export class Child {
  name = 'Angular';
  @Input() art: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [Child, RouterModule],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
  <a routerLink="child/1">1</a> | <a routerLink="child/2">2</a>
  <br/>
    <router-outlet/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(
      [
        {
          path: 'child/:id',
          component: Child,
          resolve: {
            art: (
              route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
              state: RouterStateSnapshot
            ) => {
              console.log('resolve');
              const temporaryData = route.data?.['temporaryData'];
              // delete route.data?.['temporaryData'];
              return temporaryData;
            },
          },
          canActivate: [
            (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
              console.log('guard');
              const router = inject(Router);
              const artService = inject(ArtService);
              return artService.get(route.params['id']).pipe(
                map((data: any) => {
                  route.data = { ...route.data, temporaryData: data };
                  if (!data) {
                    return router.createUrlTree(['/']);
                  }
                  return true;
                })
              );
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      withComponentInputBinding()
    ),
  ],
});

Stackblitz Demo

This is amazing! It would've taken me a very long time to figure this out. Thank you very much!

There is an issue with your code example. The artService.get(...) returns an Observable. I have to subscribe to get it to execute, but that runs asynchronously. So, the result isn't available within the synchronous context.
